# Error in Python code while using customtkinter and tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, customtkinter

When i Execute my program i get this error,

```
invalid command name "1429993768320check_dpi_scaling"
while executing
"1429993768320check_dpi_scaling"
("after" script)
```

This is the program, it should show the GUI but i get the error mentioned above.
im getting the main error in function start_scanning()
Please let me know the issue because i cannot execute it on visual studio code but the same is working on python idle. I tried making changes in start_scanning() but of no use.

```
from customtkinter import *
import customtkinter as ctk
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter as ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def start_scanning():
    main = ctk.CTk(fg_color="#101820")
    main.geometry("1000x550")


    frame1 = ctk.CTkFrame(master=main, 
                          width = 600,
                          height = 100,
                          corner_radius=0,
                          fg_color="#735DA5")
    frame1.place(relx= 0.97, rely=0.1, anchor=tk.NE)

    frame2 = ctk.CTkFrame(master=main,
                          width = 300,
                          height = 450,
                          corner_radius=0,
                          fg_color = "#D3C5E5")
    frame2.place(relx = 0.05, rely = 0.1, anchor=tk.NW)

    frame3 = ctk.CTkFrame(master = main,
                          width = 600,
                          height = 320,
                          corner_radius= 0,
                          fg_color = "#A1BE95")
    frame3.place(relx = 0.97, rely = 0.91, anchor=tk.SE)

    url_label = ctk.CTkLabel(master = frame1, 
                            text = "URL",
                            text_color="#D3C5E5",
                            font=('Arial',40,'bold'))
    url_label.place(relx = 0.04, rely = 0.3, anchor=tk.NW)


    url_input = ctk.CTkEntry(master = frame1, 
                            placeholder_text="Enter URL...",
                            width = 400,
                            height = 60)
    url_input.place(relx = 0.9, rely = 0.2, anchor = tk.NE)

    title = ctk.CTkFrame(master = frame3,
                         width = 600,
                         height = 80,
                         fg_color = "#6AB187")
    title.place(relx = 0.90, rely = 0.1, anchor=tk.SE)

    main.mainloop()

app = ctk.CTk(fg_color="#101820")
app.geometry("1000x550")

frame = ctk.CTkFrame(master=app, 
                     width=900,
                     height=450,
                     corner_radius=10,
                     fg_color="#D3C5E5")
frame.pack(padx=20, pady=20, expand=True)

label = ctk.CTkLabel(master=frame, text="BreachLock", font=('Times New Roman',50,'bold'))

image_original = Image.open('logolock.png').resize((80,80))
image_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_original)

limage = ttk.Label(frame, image = image_tk)

btn1 = ctk.CTkButton(master=frame, text="Start Scanning", text_color="#735DA5", fg_color="#D9D9D9", width=200, height=55, corner_radius=0,font=('Arial', 20,'bold'), command=start_scanning)
btn2 = ctk.CTkButton(master=frame, text="Logs", text_color="#735DA5", fg_color="#D9D9D9", width=200, height=55, corner_radius=0,font=('Arial', 20,'bold') )
btn3 = ctk.CTkButton(master=frame, text="Help", text_color="#735DA5", fg_color="#D9D9D9", width=200, height=55, corner_radius=0,font=('Arial', 20,'bold') )
btn4 = ctk.CTkButton(master=frame, text="About", text_color="#735DA5", fg_color="#D9D9D9", width=200, height=55, corner_radius=0,font=('Arial', 20,'bold') )
btn1.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.2, anchor=tk.CENTER)
btn2.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.4, anchor=tk.CENTER)
btn3.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.6, anchor=tk.CENTER)
btn4.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.8, anchor=tk.CENTER)

label.place(relx = 0.1, anchor=tk.NW)
limage.place(anchor=tk.NW)


app.mainloop()
```

Comment: You have 2 roots, main and app. Pick one. If you need 2 windows, turn one into a `tk.Toplevel`. Also, if you are even going to use ttk, at all, this: `import tkinter as ttk` should be: `import tkinter.ttk as ttk`. All you are currently doing is aliasing the base tkinter package as ttk, and not actually using ttk, at all.